# Excel spreadsheet, is there a way to have a easily inputted value such as the letter x to denote a certain value for each cell in a column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

Im running a scavenger hunt. There are 30 teams and 100 "tasks". each task is assigned a point value based on its difficulty. This make a potential for 3000 task to be completed in a 5 hour span. a potential scoring nightmare.

I am trying to make a spreadsheet that is able to quickly be filled by in each cell not by inputting the number, but to have the value of that task be able to be simply filled by typing a single letter X into the cell and having that letter have a defined value for each column.  Instead of constantly going back to reference the value of each task, it could be formulated in prior and once we mark that one of the team has completed this task it would fill with the number.

example; task #1 is worth 250 points.  I there a formula or way to do this??

Thank you in advance for any help. I hope this question makes sense.

Comment: The answer to your question ("Is there a formula or way to do this?") is "yes". It's likely a `SUMIF` could do the job. This would be easier to answer in more detail if we could see sample data

Answer (score 1):

Here are two ways to go about it:

Method 1: Use the following formula:

```
=SUMIF(C$2:C$8,"x",$B$2:$B$8)
```

and populate across the bottom of the table

Method 2: Use this formula:

```
=SUM($B$2:$B$8)-SUMIF(C$2:C$8,"",$B$2:$B$8)
```

[image]

(you'll notice method 1 only counts a score if you've entered an `x` in the cells, whereas method 2 allows for typos (see cell `F7`))

Comment: Thank you so much!  This will make the day fun for everyone (including the scorekeepers)